# не работает прибавление цены по 2м селектам

Tags: jquery

```
<form class='calc' action="">
    <select name="" id="select1">
        <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
        <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
        <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
        <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
        <option value="4">Rank 4</option>
        <option value="5">Rank 5</option>
        <option value="6">Rank 6</option>
        <option value="7">Rank 7</option>
    </select>
    <select name="" id="select2">
        <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
        <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
        <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
        <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
        <option value="4">Rank 4</option>
        <option value="5">Rank 5</option>
        <option value="6">Rank 6</option>
        <option value="7">Rank 7</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

есть небольшая форма с выбором ранков, есть зависимость цены между ними , почему не работает, подскажите нубу пожалуйста

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#totalsumm').text('0');
    $(".calc").on("change" , "select" , function(){
        var totalSumm = 0;
        if($("#select1").value=="1" && $("#select2").value=="1"){
            totalSumm += 3.26 ;
        }
        $("#totalsumm").text(totalSumm);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#totalsumm').text('0');
  $(".calc").on("change", "select", function() {
    var totalSumm = 0;
    if ($("#select1").val() == "1" && $("#select2").val() == "1") {
      totalSumm += 3.26;
    }
    $("#totalsumm").text(totalSumm);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='calc' action="">
  <select name="" id="select1">
    <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
    <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
    <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
    <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
    <option value="4">Rank 4</option>
    <option value="5">Rank 5</option>
    <option value="6">Rank 6</option>
    <option value="7">Rank 7</option>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="select2">
    <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
    <option value="1">Rank 1</option>
    <option value="2">Rank 2</option>
    <option value="3">Rank 3</option>
    <option value="4">Rank 4</option>
    <option value="5">Rank 5</option>
    <option value="6">Rank 6</option>
    <option value="7">Rank 7</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="totalsumm"></div>
```

Comment: стоп , все правильно? а чего на хосте не работает)

Comment: ааа вижууууууууу

Comment: @ИгорьАбраменков Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.